# Baffled by IE-specific routing

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, phantomjs

UPDATE: Client finally noticed they gave me an incorrect URL, even though that was my first question to them a couple of weeks ago...

That will teach me to stick to my initial gut response...
T.

I am tasked with creating a document uploading robot. The intention is to automate uploading member owned documents to an IIS-based web server.

I am implementing this using PhantomJS.

The issue I have run into is that the URL I'm supposed to be redirected to after logging in results in a 404 error **unless the login comes from Internet Explorer**.

I have set the User Agent to **Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0)**.

What else can I do to convince IIS that PhantomJS is really Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get you the specific answer to your problem but there are some things you need to consider and test.

It does not matter what browser you use. User Agents (browser) and servers communicate via HTTP. This means headers, request body, etc are the way things are identified. The User Agent string is NOT used by the server (IIS) to turn functionality on or off.

What you need to do is record the request/response dialog between the user agent (Internet Explorer in your case) and see exactly what those headers look like. Then do the same for Phantom, Chrome and any other user agent you can test against.

See what the headers, status codes, etc are and see what is different. Then make sure those values are supplied from PhantomJS. My guess is there is some sort of authentication credential being passed in IE that is not being defined in Phantom.

** Also note, MSFT started deprecating IE 18 months ago. It is only 'alive' for legacy enterprise web sites. So you may want to move on for any new web projects and set the minimum to the latest browser versions and one back. :)